# Delphi 2005 freezes where entering a sql line

Tags: delphi, freeze, tadoquery, delphi-2005

I've a problem that I'm not able to solve.

I've a project in delphi 2005 and I created a form by copying an old one, editing its name and programming the changes I want.

The application works fine, but when I'm writting source code and I enter into a line with

```
adoquery1.sql.add(blah, blah, blah);  // just an example
```

it freezes during a few seconds and the bds proccess uses 25% of the cpu. It happens only on this form and I don't know why.

Any hint?

Comment: I've solved it by creating a new file with the notepad, copying the source code into in, saving it with the original name and replacing the old one with this. Now it works but I'd like to know why happened...

Comment: Delphi 2005 is probably the buggiest version of Delphi ever released. Perhaps try to get your project to a more recent release.